# How can I use custom sorting on an NSTableView bound to an NSArrayController?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder, nstableview, nsarraycontroller

I have an `NSTableView` connected to an `NSArrayController` by setting the column values in interface builder to the appropriate keys in the `NSArrayController`.  I'd like to use a custom sorting order, specifically, compare:options: with `NSNumericSearch`.  Where can I either change my code to do this, or tell interface builder to use a different comparison selector?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how well this would work with an ArrayController, but you might look into NSTableColumn's [-setSortDescriptorPrototype:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableColumn_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (passing your columns your own sort descriptor in code).